# HTTP SMS Push for PHP Not Working

Tags: php, http, sms

Can someone help me about sending an SMS via HTTP for PHP? I'm using OneWaySMS Philippines, and it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the API code sample they provided:

```
function gw_send_sms($user, $pass, $sms_from, $sms_to, $sms_msg)
{
    $query_string = "api.aspx?apiusername=" . $user . "&apipassword=" . $pass;
    $query_string .= "&senderid=" . rawurlencode($sms_from) . "&mobileno=" . rawurlencode($sms_to);
    $query_string .= "&message=" . rawurlencode(stripslashes($sms_msg)) . "&languagetype=1";
    $url = "http://gateway.onewaysms.com.au:10001/" . $query_string;
    $fd = @implode('', file($url));

    if ($fd) {
        if ($fd > 0) {
            Print("MT ID : " . $fd);
            $ok = "success";
        } else {
            print("Please refer to API on Error : " . $fd);
            $ok = "fail";
        }
    } else {
        // no contact with gateway
        $ok = "fail";
    }

    return $ok;
}

Print("Sending to one way sms " . gw_send_sms("apiusername", "apipassword", "senderid", "61412345678", "test message"));
```

This is my code (I went really far changing it since the simple one didn't work):

```
function gw_send_sms($user, $pass, $sms_from, $sms_to, $sms_msg)
{
    $query_string = "api.aspx?apiusername=" . $user . "&apipassword=" . $pass;
    $query_string .= "&senderid=" . rawurlencode($sms_from) . "&mobileno=" . rawurlencode($sms_to);
    $query_string .= "&message=" . rawurlencode(stripslashes($sms_msg)) . "&languagetype=1";
    $url = "http://gateway.onewaysms.com.ph:10001/" . $query_string;
    $arr = array($url);
    $fd = implode(',', $arr);

    if ($fd) {
        if ($fd > 0) {
            Print("MT ID : " . $fd);
            $ok = "success";
        } else {
            print("Please refer to API on Error : " . $fd);
            $ok = "fail";
        }
    } else {
        // no contact with gateway                      
        $ok = "fail";
    }

    return $ok;
}

Print("Sending to one way sms " . gw_send_sms("sampleusername", "samplepassword", "Sender", "SampleNumber", "Testing SMS"));
```

> Please refer to API on Error :
>   http://gateway.onewaysms.com.ph:10001/api.aspx?apiusername=sample&apipassword=sample&senderid=sample&mobileno=sample&message=Testing%20omg&languagetype=1
>   Sending to one way sms fail

I also tried going directly to the URL, but with no luck.

Comment: what output do you see? also have you tried typing the entire query with url into the browser? try that and post back what results you get because its possible you are using a incorrect login/password or that your account isnt yet active.

Comment: Please clearify what "I doesn't work" mean. Do you see error messages?

Comment: I updated the post with the error messages.

Comment: I still can't see the error message?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Did you click the link? The phone number I indicated just received the messages. What did you do if ever it was you? Haha.

Comment: @Christian I think I clicked it once, but didn't do anything special!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong domain, it should be gateway.onewaysms.ph not gateway.onewaysms.com.ph.

Comment: Thanks! You're a life saver, couldn't have noticed that. I already changed the credentials a few minutes earlier. I did not notice that as well, gee.

Comment: @Christian People can still view the credentials in the question's history, so make sure you change them at the provider end.